# How can we store failed messages in VM Connector iin MULE

Tags: mule, virtual-machine

How can we store failed messages in VM Connector in MULE
Assume it is a transient flow .

Scenario is like when ever mule server is down and at the same time messages sent to publish connector.

what will be best way. Hope I am clear or bear with me for any confusion.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM connector works like a queue in memory, but it is not an external message broker like for example ActiveMQ or IBM MQ. The VM connector implementation is inside the Mule Runtime implementation. It can not be used to send messages to other Mule servers, nor other non-Mule applications. Also if the Mule Runtime instance is down, then it will not work at all so there is not way to publish nor receive messages. If you want that kind of reliability you need to use an external JMS message broker.